# Do implementations of dynamic arrays reserve space at the beginning, for prepending?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays, prepend

Basic implementations of [dynamic arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) are size 2n, where half of the space is populated by existing elements, and the other half is reserved **at the end** for appending new elements in O(1) time.

Inserting new elements anywhere other than at the end of the array requires reallocation of the array, which is an expensive operation.

Are there any C++ implementations of resizable arrays, where space is also reserved at the beginning of the array, for prepending elements efficiently? If so, how much space is reserved compared to the space reserved at the end for appending? I would imagine prepending is a much less common operation, but if it is happening often enough in a program, it could be devastating to reallocate upon each prepending operation.

Comment: I think you're describing `std::deque`.

Comment: @MarkRansom http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/

Comment: `Inserting new elements anywhere other than at the end of the array requires reallocation of the array` False. Inserting an element reallocate the array if the reserved space is full, regardless where that element is inserted. The difference between inserting at the end and elsewhere is that inserting elsewhere will move following elements (shift them). So you can insert at the beginning of the array without reallocation if you have reserved space, but of course it will move all elements 1 position to the right.

Comment: @bolov  That's still an O(n) operation, as opposed to O(1) for prepending in a `deque`, or appending in either.

Comment: @sgarza62 true, I just pointed out it is not true that it always reallocates the array. The effect is the same: O(n) complexity, the cause is different.

Comment: @bolov  Yes of course, I was just adding more useful information to the exchange. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Yes the structures you describe do exist, they're just hard to find because they don't seem to have a unique name.  I've encountered them on this site in several places, and written two myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Deques](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/) allow for prepending and appending in amortized constant time.

Unlike [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), where the array is stored contiguously and reallocated if capacity is reached, deque elements are not guaranteed to be stored contiguously. Instead, deques store elements in chunks. If more space is needed as a result of a [push_back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/push_back/) or [push_front()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/push_front/) call, a new chunk of space is allocated and linked to.

Thank you to [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) for posting about deques in the comments.

Comment: implementation of `deque` is mostly… well implementation specific. The standard specifies restrictions of operations like constant random access, amortized O(1) of insertion at begining / end etc.. Chunks and chunk sizes are specific to each implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the thanks. I think though that you meant `capacity` and not `max_size`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't hear of any such implementation. However, if you do not require elements to be ordered in the memory as they are in the container, you could use std::list and have O(1) on insertion anywhere.